# is their a way using which i can update the ignore_above field without deleting my index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index in elasticsearch v7.3 with parent child relationship and i have indexed child documents before indexing parent documents so firstly i wanted to know if that's okay and then i have a field in my index whose ignore_above value has to be increased from an existing 256 so can i do it without deleting my index.

It's ok with me if the data for that specific field gets lost for existing documents but for indexing documents from now on i want that ignore_above limit for that specific field to get increased so can i do it?

```
PUT /test/_mapping
{
 "properties": {
  "handles": {
   "type": "text",
   "ignore_above": 1000 
  }
 }
}
```

Currently i am getting this error,

```
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "Mapping definition for [handles] has unsupported parameters:  [ignore_above : 1000]"
```

so please help me in resolving this query.

Comment: The `ignore_above` parameter is only available for `keyword` fields, not on `text` fields. But yes, if your field was of type `keyword`, you'd be [allowed to update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) the `ignore_above` setting.

Comment: actually i have dynamic mappings in my index so can i write such a template where i can tell it to index fields as type keyword only.

Comment: Then if you do, you can directly set the `ignore_above` parameter to the right value in the dynamic mapping. No need to update it afterwards.

Comment: ok, also i wanted to know if i index all the child docs first with correct routing and parent doc after it with the same id that was given in child doc routing then that will be ok and both parent and child doc will be on same shard, or is it necessary to index parent doc before the child doc's ??

Comment: That's a different question, I suggest you create another thread so we don't mix topics.

Comment: please if u could give the answer in a yes or no that would be helpful for me. I would definitely post it afterwards.

Comment: Yes, you sure can.

Answer (score 0):

The `ignore_above` parameter is only available for `keyword` fields, not on `text` fields. But yes, if your field was of type `keyword`, you'd be [allowed to update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) the `ignore_above` setting for that field.

Since you're using [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html), you could set the right value for `ignore_above` at index creation time.